# CheckboxList TreeView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, treeview, jstree, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckboxList` in *ASP.NET* which I'd like to convert to a `TreeView` using something like *jsTree*. Is this possible? The nodes are nested up to four levels deep with *CheckboxLists* inside *CheckboxLists*. Is it possible to magically turn them into a `TreeView` or will I need to tinker all day with *JS* in the code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can calculate "Depth" of each node, you can add the following code to OnPreRender and will show your items hierarchical:

```
protected void overrided OnPreRender()
{
    lstItems.Items.Do(a=>
    {
        var item = // get item from a.Value
        for(var i = 0; i< item.Depth; i++)
        {
            a.Text = "<span class='spacer'></span>" + a.Text;
        }
    });
}
```

and add the following rule to your stylesheets:

```
span.spacer { width:20px; }
```

Although if you want to have collapse/expand feature you will need to add some javascript actions which I won't include here (too keep it simple)

P.S. It is important that items added to lstItems is ordered correctly based on hierarchical structure. Solution I recommend is to use the following method as the sort key of your datasource:

```
public string GetFullPath()
{
    if(Parent == null) return Key;
    return Parent.GetFullPath() + ">" + Key;
}
```

Where Key is a unique field (in the context of a single parent). - It can be name, order, etc.

Comment: Interesting option, but I eventually went with a RadTreeView. It offered the most flexibility for the least amount of work (sadly not free though)

Comment: Yes, not free, that's the main reason I go for this approach. Although if you implement this once (as an extension method or something) you can use it forever.